# how to implement wireless star topology network for 100 end device with single hop?

Tags: zigbee

What is the the best technology or protocol with which to implement a short range wireless network that has more than 100 end devices. This network should use a single hop star topology for the sake of power saving.

The purpose of this is to make sure that all of the mobile sensors are within the range of a coordinator area and to make an alarm if one of the sensors has left the coordinator area.

I hope my question is clear.

Thank you.

Comment: Bluetooth low energy would probably suit this application (or Bluetooth Smart for the politically correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more specific requirements, it's hard to give good advice.

From the little information I have, it sounds like Wi-Fi is a good technology for your needs.  However, you mention power consumption as a concern.  If you need to transfer lots of data, Wi-Fi is more energy efficient (J/bit) than many low power wireless technologies.

In Bluetooth, [Piconets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piconet) are limited to 8 devices, and I would imagine you would be pretty congested.  I don't know if Bluetooth Low Energy shares this design.

[IEEE 802.15.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.15.4) is the PHY and MAC used by ZigBee.  It can also be used with a [6LoWPAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6LoWPAN) stack, which is designed to interoperate with the internet at large using similar standards (e.g. IPv6) and principles (e.g. end-to-end, RESTful).

[ANT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANT_%28network%29) is worth mentioning as well.  It is another Personal Area Networking tech which facilities small data transfers for very low power devices.

There are all sorts of chips and modules which implement some or all of these technologies (sometimes all in the same package).  If you need to transfer lots of data, Wi-Fi is the best.  If you are transmitting small amounts of data, look into more into the finer details of BLE, 802.15.4 and ANT to determine which might be best for your needs.

Comment: thank you for your reply , so can I use 802.15.4  protocol to implement a single hop star topology that has one coordinator and 100 End device without any router ?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to have 100 devices connected to one coordinator.  The limit seems to be 254.  I am getting this information from here: http://www.sinemergen.com/zigbee.pdf.  If you are considering 802.15.4 and/or ZigBee, it seems like a great read.  You will still have some sort of routing layer, even if it is dead simple, but that sits above 802.15.4.  ZigBee has a standardized routing layer, and I would guess that there are several choices of routing 6LoWPAN traffic.

Comment: can I implement this buy using a simple simulator ?

Comment: If you are looking for an extremely Low Power, Long Range, Proprietary Sub1G star network you can look at: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/SimpleLink-EasyLink